# powershell new-item only saves the last line to the file

Tags: powershell

I renaming all files in one directory and doing a content replace on to save them and saving them as new files

why is it when I echo the value of $newText it shows all the text, but when i pipe that same variable to new-item, I only get the last line?

example... in the current directory I have a file called `TemplateClient_.TemplateProject_.txt` with 3 lines of text in it

```
TemplateClient_/TemplateProject_ 
test text
end
```

when i run the powershell script it creates the file `Aaaa.Bbbb.txt`, but it only has one line, the last line. it just says `end`

```
    $text = get-content $file.fullname
    $newText = $text -creplace $currentClient,$newClient  
    $newText = $newText -creplace $currentProject,$newProject 

    echo  $newText
    $newFileLoc = $file.fullname.replace($currentClient, $newClient).replace($currentProject, $newProject)
    $newText | new-item -force -path $newFileLoc  -type "file"
```

---

**Solution:**

```
$currentClient = "TemplateClient_"
$currentProject = "TemplateProject_"
$newClient = "Aaaa"
$newProject = "Bbbb"

$files = Get-ChildItem $(get-location) -include *.txt  -Recurse 

foreach($file in $files) 
{
    $fileText = get-content $file.fullname
    $fileText = $fileText -creplace $currentClient,$newClient  
    $fileText = $fileText -creplace $currentProject,$newProject 

    $newFileLoc = $file.fullname.replace($currentClient, $newClient).replace($currentProject, $newProject)
    new-item -force -path $newFileLoc  -type "file" 
    Set-Content $fileText -Path $newFileLoc
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
Set-Content $newText -Path $newFileLoc
```

or

```
$newText | Set-Content $newFileLoc
```

Comment: great , this works. I did however have to add     new-item -force -path $newFileLoc  -type "file"  before so that the file would be there. Otherwise Set-Content throws an error that it cant find the file.  thanks :)

Comment: I'm using ps v3, set-content will create the file if not exist. Maybe some permission issue cause the "file not exist error" you met. [set-content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849828.aspx) says "if the file does not exist, the command will create it." in example 2.

Comment: i just updated my powershell to v3. it gives me "Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path" . there are however directories that do not exist. should set-content create directories?

Comment: `set-content` will not create directories. in my psv3 installation, your original `$newText | New-Item $newFileLoc -Force -Type "File"` command could work, `new-item` could create directories not exists with `-force`